# css not loading after upgrading rails version to 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, upgrade

I have upgraded my application from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.2, I am facing an issue in CSS, as it is not loading properly. Before using `asset-pipeline`, I had been using `jammit` for assets precompile. I found the following message in the log:

```
Started GET "/assets/js_templates.jst" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 17:41:59 +0530   
Processing by Jammit::Controller#package as */*     
Parameters: {"package"=>"js_templates", "extension"=>"jst"}   
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)   
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 225ms  

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template errors/page_not_found, 
application/page_not_found with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:jpeg], :handlers=>[:erb, 
:builder, :coffee, :haml]}
```

Comment: Can you post your gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by using the following:
In rails 3.0.1,

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
    def page_not_found
        render :status => 404
    end
end
```

In rails 3.2 changed the render to respond_to

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
    def page_not_found
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :status => 404 }
        format.any { head :status=>404 }
    end
end
```